# progressBlock in getDataInBackgroundWithBlock not called

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My Swift app uses Parse.com as the backend. Among other things, I store images for user profiles. I store two versions of the same image: one thumbnail and one full sized image. When the user taps on the thumbnail, it is enlarged. The app then loads the full sized version and presents it on top of the enlarged thumbnail when loading is complete. Since the thumbnail image looks blurry while the full sized one is loading, I've implemented a circular progress bar that shows the loading progress, giving visual feedback of what's going on.

This is the method that handles this process (`progressCircle` is a `CAShapeLayer`):

```
func fetchFullImage() {
    photoObject.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (fetchedObject: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // After fetching object, now we get the full sized image
            let userFullImageFile = fetchedObject["fullImage"] as PFFile

            userFullImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock( {
                (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    println(">> Success! Full image retrieved.")
                    self.fullImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                    // Hide the progress indicator
                    self.progressCircle.hidden = true 

                    // Fade in and show the image
                    self.showFullImage()
                }
            },
            progressBlock: {(percentDone: CInt) -> Void in
                println("Loading... \(percentDone)")
                // Prints out progress percentage under wifi, but not under 3G!

                self.progressCircle.strokeEnd = CGFloat(percentDone) / 100.0
            })

        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is the funny part. When I run the app on a real device connected via wifi, everything goes as expected: the progress circle grows as the image is loaded, etc. Now when I turn off wifi and the same device is connected via 3G, the progress circle does not grow. Essentially, what happens is that the `progressBlock` closure is not called (I can see this because the `println` statement produces no result). The image loads after a while (the completion closure *is* called), and is presented correctly, but there is no way for me to show the progress.

I am trying to find the logic behind this. I could almost understand it if it was the opposite (image loading so fast over wifi that the progress was not visible), but over 3G images take a few seconds to load, during which period nothing seems to happen.

Does anyone have an idea of what can keep `progressBlock` from being called here? I want to be able to provide the "loading in progress" visual feedback.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not try to update the UI from a background thread. Use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {...}. Maybe not related to your problem, but you should still fix it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I thought the whole point of that progressBlock was to be able to update UI elements, but after reading your comment I found other references about not updating the UI from background threads. Added dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()). However, and as expected, this didn't fix my issue, which seems to be Parse related.